# Creating Database on client's machine with its connection details

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, winforms

I have created a desktop application in VS 2010 with SQL Server 2008 as a back end.
When I created my application's exe and tried to install it on client's machine, it obviously asked me for a SQL DB instance. But I have my own connection string with its data source name specific to my machine only, How can I make my application work like, it should create required DB when I install it on client's machine. (I have installed SQL server 2008 on client's machine).
I tried below code to create DB on client's machine, But I get error:40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

```
String str;
SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection ("Server=localhost;Integrated security=SSPI;database=master");
str = "CREATE DATABASE MyDatabase"
SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(str, myConn);
try 
{
    myConn.Open();
myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
MessageBox.Show("DataBase is Created Successfully", "MyProgram", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
catch (System.Exception ex)
{
MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "MyProgram", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
finally
{
if (myConn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
{
    myConn.Close();
}
}
```

Any suggestions would be of great help! Thanks!

Comment: Don't use sql server as a client/desktop database! Use an in-process engine like Sql Server Compact Edition, Sqlite, or even access.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn or [VistaDB](http://vistadb.net).

Comment: Hey Joel, I am a complete new bee to .net. It would be good if you can provide some link to an example showing how to use SQL Compact edition. i mean, setting up the connection, creating DB, tables etc. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Do I need to rework with my developed application? I mean, DO I need to change the code for SQL Server 2008 to SQL Server compact edition?

Comment: @TouhidK. You will need to change some queries, and use the SqlCe rather than SqlClient namespace, and there is a package to include with your installer (2 dll files). Normally, this is the kind of thing you figure out before you get to the deployment stage.